# powershell script mix variable with parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm building a powershell script where part of it changes the permissions on several resource calendars. The normal command is (which works, no problem):

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "ResourceCalendar:\Calendar" -user Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

I've tried using:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$line.name:\Calendar" -user Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

and

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $line.name:\Calendar -user Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

But it keeps throwing errors.

The variable works everywhere else - its being captured from a CSV it imports at the beginning of the script. its something to do with the :\Calendar that i cant connect to it.

Comment: "it keeps throwing errors" - what errors? (You have to tell us, because we can't see your screen.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When [the parser evaluates parameter arguments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx), it treats them as expandable strings - that means that `$line.name` is interpreted the same way as:

```
$line + ".name"
```

To dereference a property of a variable, use the subexpression operator `$()`:

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity "$($line.name):\Calendar" -user Default -AccessRights Reviewer
```

Now, everything inside `$()` will be evaluated a PowerShell expression.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what it needed :)

Comment: But Mathias R. Jessen - if you just answer it like that, the OP isn't "encouraged" to include the relevant details in the question. :)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Enough information was included to show an obvious and common misunderstanding, what else do you need?

Comment: The point isn't that you understood it. The point is that the OP didn't include the error message in the original question. My comment was intended to point this out to help him or her in the future.